# How to render p:selectOneMenu inside an editable p:dataTable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, glassfish-3

I would like to render `p:selectOneMenu` inside `p:dataTable` upon `rowEditInit` event.  I tried `update="degreeType"`, `update=formid:editTable:degreeType` but it didn't work.  `update="@this` is not a option as it refreshes whole table and clears the edit selection.  As it is a dataTable, the exact id for the element is `formid:editTable:0:degreeType`, `0` being row number.  How should I get the current row id number and put in `update` field?

```
<p:dataTable id="editTable" value="#{bean.emp}" var="stud" disabledSelection="true" editable="true" >
    <p:ajax event="rowEditInit" listener="#{bean.onRowInit}" update="degreeType"/>
    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{bean.onRowEdit}" />
    <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{bean.onRowCancel}" />
    <!-- a bunch of p:column tags -->
    <p:column headerText="Degree">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{stud.degree}" /></f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{stud.degree}" style="width: 100%" >
                    <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{bean.degreeListener}"  render="degreeType" />
                    <f:selectItem  itemLabel="Select One" itemValue=""/>
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="MS" itemValue="MS"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="BS" itemValue="BS"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>   
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="DegreeType">
        <p:cellEditor id="test">
            <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{stud.degreeType}" /></f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:selectOneMenu id="degreeType" value="#{stud.degreeType}" rendered="true">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true"/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{stud.degreeTypes}"/> 
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>

    <p:column style="width: 30px">
        <p:rowEditor />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?